# Update with NULL columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

```
Quantity | Response | Month | Year | Name
__________________________________________
2365      'Response1'  3      2014  (null)
1420      'Response2'  3      2014  'Name1'
2365      'Response1'  3      2014  (null)
 750      (null)       3      2014  'Name2'
  65      (null)       3      2014  (null)
```

I'm running this update in a stored procedure

```
update Table1 
set Quantity = q, 
    Response = resp, 
    Month = monthv, 
    Year = yearv, 
    Name = namescreen   
where   Month = monthv 
    and Year = yearv 
    and Response = resp 
    and Name = namescreen;
```

the columns with null values are not getting updated

```
Quantity | Response | Month | Year | Name
__________________________________________
2365      'Response1'  3      2014  (null)
1500      'Response2'  3      2014  'Name1'
2365      'Response1'  3      2014  (null)
 750      (null)       3      2014  'Name2'
  65      (null)       3      2014  (null)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Because [NULL isn't equal to NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Controversy).

Comment: `and Response=resp`: if trying to update a column with a NULL value, wrap in an NVL using a dummy value: `and NVL(Response, '-1') = NVL(resp, '-1')`

Comment: @Glenn That can work, but only if there is a specific value that does not exist in the table, and never will. Otherwise, it's just a matter of time until you get a false positive and update the wrong row.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question why you think these rows should be updated, but to check for `NULL` values you have to use `IS NULL`. This is because `NULL` is interpreted as 'Unknown' in standard SQL. This means that most conditional checks that involve null values will also yield 'Unknown'.

Consider this truth table:

```
c1   | c2    | c1 AND c2  | c1 OR c2
----------------------------------
null | true  | null      | true
null | null  | null      | null
null | false | false     | null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update Table1 set Quantity=q, Response=resp, Month=monthv, Year=yearv, Name=namescreen   
where Month = monthv and Year=yearv and Response=resp and Name=namescreen;
```

your saying UPDATE TABLES WHICH ARE HAVE ALL THE RAWS use this

```
update Table1 set Quantity=q, Response=resp, Month=monthv, Year=yearv, Name=namescreen   
where Quantity=q;
```

you have to check use where in one value not both of them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using the same value in your SET statement that you're using in your WHERE clause -- but that's one (potential) problem.  (Update month = April where month already = April...can you see it?)  Usually you'd either use a key to find the record, or else use two variables -- old value and new value -- for example:

```
SET Year = new_yearv WHERE Year = old_yearv
```

or

```
SET Year = yearv WHERE primary_key_field = 5
```

The other problem (potentially) is that you might not be passing your stored procedure NULL values like you think.  Could be they're converting to empty strings before they're passed or something like that.  Anyway, try something like this:

```
WHERE (Year=yearv OR Year IS NULL) AND (Month = monthv OR Month IS NULL), etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only want to set the quantity when the columns match the input values.  This query should accomplish that:

```
update Table1 
    set Quantity = q 
where (Month = monthv or Month is null and monthv is null) and
      (Year = yearv or Year is null and yearv is null) and
      (Response = resp or Response is null and resp is null) and
      (Name = namescreen or Name is NULL or namescreen is null);
```